# ground state energy of a wavefcn with bisection method

Tags: python, physics, bisection

I am looking for the ground state energy of the wavefcn that can fit in a given potential:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
ximin=-8
ximax=-ximin
Nsteps=1001
nu0=4.0

psi = np.linspace(ximin,ximax,Nsteps)
h = psi[1] - psi[0]

v = -nu0*np.exp(-psi**2) #potential

Emin = -3.5 #first two guesses

Emax = -2.0




while ((Emin- Emax)/(Emin + Emax) > 10**(-8)): #tolerance
if abs(fi[-1]) > abs(10**(-8)): #condition that the wavefcn doesnt blow up
    Eo = (Emin + Emax)/2.0
    if fi[-1] < -10**(-8): #blows down
        Emax = Eo
    if fi[-1] > 10**(-8): #blows up
        Emin = Eo
else:
    break

fi = np.zeros(Nsteps)
fi[0]= 1
k = (-Eo)**(0.5)
fi[1] = np.exp(k*h)

for i in range(2,len(psi)):
    fi[i]=(2+h**2 * (v[i-1]-Eo))*fi[i-1]-fi[i-2] #wavefcn



plt.plot(psi, fi)
```

the idea is that when the energy that we plug in is wrong, the wavefcn either blows up or down. Then for example we take an energy that is in the middle between the previous two and if that one blows up, then we will look for a new value between this last one and the one that blows down and so on . I should get a good energy value but I dont. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you include a concrete example with the contents of `fi` and the result you expect?